# What are some of the main high level approaches for analysis of kinematic sensor data?

Tags: motion

I'm a computer vision and deep learning specialist. I've just started a project which will involve having to detect certain events in a stream of kinematic sensor data. By searching through the literature, I've found a lot of highly specific papers, but no general reviews.

If I search up on computer vision, I'm likely to get 100s of articles giving overviews of different types of architectures for various vision tasks. They would look something like this:

- We mainly use CNNs which work like this ...
- For object detection we use one or two stage detectors which look like this...
- For video classification we can use 3D CNNs or RNNs...
- .... etc

So I'm looking for something similar with regard to kinematic motion sensors.

Comment: Wellllll for computer vision, your problem is already much more well-defined (you're trying to detect specific objects' presence in a specific kind of 2D data). You're just saying "kinematic sensor" and "some events": That's way way way less specific than saying "object recognition in cognitive vision". So, playing that ball back into your field. What's the nature of the sensor data? is it 1D? Is it multidimensional? If so, what are the dimensions, how do they relate? And also, kind of importantly, what's an "event" to you? People tend to use that, but then forget that it's not clear.

Comment: Adding on the previous comment, a "kinematic sensor" could mean many things. This could be a distance sensor, a gyroscope, or something else. The data you get for each of these is very different but it is sensor data. It is quite straight forward and does not need many papers. A distance sensor will output the distance. What you do with that information is unrelated to the kinematic sensor. Comparing to "computer vision", it is like asking for papers on a camera's CCD (also a sensor) and not papers on computer vision.

Comment: @MarcusMüller and havakok thanks for nudging me on the right track. I have accelerometers in 3d, gyro in 3d, and 3d magnetic field sensor for absolute orientation. These will all be give out signals in time. I want to be able to detect certain activities on a bicycle. I'll welcome answers for the specific use case, although I was also wondering if there are some general techniques that are used for the broader task of event detection in the type of data I've just mentioned